# Storing cache/session(Key and Value) in AWS Elasticache Redis cluster using .net SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, memcached, aws-sdk, amazon-elasticache

I have to Store the session logs(in form of Key, Value) in Elasticache Redis cluster using AWS .net SDK.
But I could see only memcached cluster related methods in .net SDK. But I need to store the logs in RedisCluster.
 * Could anyone Suggest the steps to store the logs in Redis Clster using AWS .net SDK.

Thanks,
Prakash

Comment: why would that be any different from using a non-aws redis instance?

Comment: My dev teams use https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/ but there are other .net redis libraries out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both Memcache and Redis clusters on AWS, you do not read/write data using the AWS SDKs. Just like databases on RDS, the AWS SDK helps you managed the servers/instances. They are not used for data access.

To access Redis data in ElastiCache, you would use any of the publicly available Redis client libraries for C#:

[List of C# Clients on redis.io](https://redis.io/clients#c)